# Can't enable Siri in High Sierra?

Tags: mac, siri

#### When I click "Enable Ask Siri" in the `Siri Preferences Panel`

- I get a message saying `Siri sends information like your voice input, contacts, and location to Apple to process your request`
- I click `Enable`
- The dialog dismisses, and `Enable Ask Siri` is still unchecked.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Note I've rebooted, and ensured `Notification Center` is enabled, as mentioned in things I see when googling about this issue.

Note that this is a work computer, so it may have this feature disabled in some way? I have another work computer that it works fine on, both running High Sierra.

Here are the log messages from the `Console.app`

```
error   12:20:48.173926 -0300   siriknowledged  -[CKEventHandler setupNotifyHandlers]_block_invoke Received XPC event from notifyd: <private>
error   12:20:48.181428 -0300   siriknowledged  -[CKEventHandler setupNotifyHandlers]_block_invoke Received XPC event from notifyd: <private>
default 12:20:48.183930 -0300   suggestd    PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:48.184209 -0300   silhouette  PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:48.194735 -0300   suggestd    PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:48.194972 -0300   silhouette  PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:48.200372 -0300   suggestd    PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:48.205963 -0300   suggestd    PPPortrait read Siri as disabled.
default 12:20:49.271304 -0300   SiriNCService   remote_device_copy_unique_of_type: device not found
default 12:20:49.271532 -0300   SiriNCService   remote_device_copy_unique_of_type: device not found
```

Comment: If you think it may be disabled your first avenue for a solution is to find out from your IT department if it is, indeed, disabled. Please do so and edit your question to reflect if your IT department does or does not disable Siri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, turns out IT at our company has disabled `Siri` as a corporate policy, at least according to our tech support.

Why it works on a corporate laptop and not a corporate desktop, both running High Sierra, I'm not sure!